# Update Image with modal -file on server, name in db

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, modal-dialog, image-upload

I have a modal where i update the name and description of a place in a db. I want to make it to also update the image. The image is getting uploaded on a server, in db I save only the name. Name and description update fine but the image wont update, I have tried but it hasnt work, I cant understand where my mistake is. It acts like its updated with submit, no error, but its still the old image. Here is my code, I hope for your help, pls and thanks.

script.js

```
function UpdatePlaceDetails() {
var name = $("#update_name").val();
var description = $("#update_description").val();
var pimage = $("#update_image").val();  

var place_id = $("#hidden_place_id").val();

$.post("updatePlaceDetails.php", {
        place_id: place_id,
        name: name,
        description: description,
        pimage: pimage  
    },
    function (data, status) {
        $("#update_place_modal").modal("hide");            
        window.location.reload(true); 
    }
);}
```

updatePlaceDetails.php

```
if(isset($_POST))
{   $place_id = $_POST['place_id'];
    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $description = trim($_POST['description']); 

        if(!empty($_FILES["update_image"]["name"])){

            $upload_image = $_FILES["update_image"]["name"]; 
            $folder = "images/";    

            move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["update_image"]["tmp_name"] , $folder.$upload_image ); 

            try {
                $query = $dbh ->prepare("UPDATE places SET pimage = :pimage WHERE place_id = :place_id");               
                $query->bindParam(':pimage', $pimage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':place_id', $place_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();} 
        }

        try {
                $query2 = $dbh ->prepare("UPDATE places SET name = :name, description = :description, pimage = :pimage WHERE place_id = :place_id");
                $query2->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query2->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);               
                $query2->bindParam(':pimage', $pimage, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query2->bindParam(':place_id', $place_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query2->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();  }

        if (!$result = $query2 ){
            exit($dbh->errorInfo());
        }}
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="update_place_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="update_name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="update_name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="update_description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="update_description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="update_image">Image</label>                    
              <input type="file" id="update_image" placeholder="Image"/>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="UpdatePlaceDetails()" >Save Changes</button>
            <input type="hidden" id="hidden_place_id">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you confirm that it is still the old image? By opening the file in the server? Or just by loading the file/image in the browser?

Comment: by loading the image in the browser

Comment: My guess is that the file was uploaded and changed in the server side, but browser cached it and that is why you still see the old image.

Comment: from the server I can only see the name of the image and still is old image's name, it hasnt gotten the new name. Could still be this case?

Comment: No. Did you check logs from the server?

Comment: Doesn't seem something wrong there.. did you see my code above? Am I doing it the tight way?